# Javascript String with Single Quote printed from PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

I have following script printed from PHP . If some one has a single quote in description it shows javascript error missing ; as it thinks string terminated .

```
print   "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n
    var Obj = new Array();\n
     Obj.title        = '{$_REQUEST['title']}'; 
     Obj.description     = '{$_REQUEST['description']}';
     </script>";
```

Form does a post to this page and title and description comes from textbox.Also I am unable to put double quotes around {$_REQUEST['title']} as it shows syntax error . How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a more clean (and secure) way to do it (imo):

```
<?php 
//code here

$title = addslashes(strip_tags($_REQUEST['title']));
$description = addslashes(strip_tags($_REQUEST['description']));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var Obj = new Array();
 Obj.title = '<?php echo $title?>'; 
 Obj.description = '<?php echo $description?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah. I think `strip_tags()` does not add security here. All it will do is add another possibility to break user input (as it might eat stuff like `< 200`)

Comment: I *think* a pure `addslashes()` should be safe enough. I can't think of a way to break that (although @Mike shows a potential one above)

Comment: actually, I think you're right: It is indeed worth adding `strip_tags()` to prevent breaking out from the script as @Mike shows underneath my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You also need to be careful with things like line breaks. JavaScript strings can't span over multiple lines. [json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines) is the way to go. (Adding this as new answer because of code example.)

```
<?php

$_REQUEST = array(
    'title'       => 'That\'s cool',
    'description' => 'That\'s "hot"
                      & not cool</script>'
);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var Obj = new Array();
 Obj.title = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['title'], JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
 Obj.description = <?php echo json_encode($_REQUEST['description'], JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;

 alert(Obj.title + "\n" + Obj.description);
</script>
```

---

**Edit (2016-Nov-15):** Adds `JSON_HEX_TAG` parameter to `json_encode` calls. I *hope* this solves all issues when writing data into JavaScript within `<script>` elements. There are some [rather annoying corner cases](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#script-content-restrictions).

Answer (score -1):

Use the string concatenation operator:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

```
print   "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n
    var Obj = new Array();\n
     Obj.title        = '".$_REQUEST['title']."'; 
     Obj.description     = '".$_REQUEST['description']."';
     </script>";
```

Comment: Will not fix the OP's problem

Comment: I was under the impression that the second part of the question was a php syntax error caused by typing something like this: Obj.title = '"{$_REQUEST['title']"';